# How to show values related to a max() grouped by another column

Tags: sql

I'm using this code to join two tables and get the highest salary from each location

```
SELECT 
       max(sal) [Salary],
       loc [Location]
FROM   dept
INNER JOIN emp
   ON dept.deptno = emp.dept
group by loc
```

how can i get the name of the person with the max salary together with the location?

tried this, but it shows all entries on table

```
SELECT 
       max(sal) [Salary],
       loc [Location],
       ename [names]
FROM   dept
INNER JOIN emp
   ON dept.deptno = emp.dept
group by loc,ename
```

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT d.loc, e.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.loc ORDER BY salary DESC) as seqnum
      FROM dept JOIN
           emp
           ON dept.deptno = emp.dept
     ) e
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```